# Is it possible to color some words in a UITextView in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsattributedstring, nstextstorage

I'm trying to color some words in a UITextView in an iPhone app but I'm getting an error and I'm starting to think that maybe it is not possible...
I'm using this code:

```
 -(void)colorText
{
NSString *word = @"duck";

NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: explainationTV.text];


NSUInteger count = 0;
NSUInteger length = [attrString length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);

while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    range = [[attrString string] rangeOfString:word options:0 range:range];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [attrString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [word length])];
        [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [word length])];
        range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
        count++;
    }

}


     [[self.explainationTV textStorage] setAttributedString:attrString];
 }
```

and I'm getting this error:

> -[UITextView textStorage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f26ca00
>   2013-10-16 20:59:41.711 My App[19795:913] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextView textStorage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f26ca00'

I'm using the same code in a Mac app and it works fine... anyone knows if I am doing something wrong or it simply can not work in iPhone app?
Thanks for any help... Massy

Comment: refer NSAttributedString in IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably meant to use

```
self.explainationTV.attributedText = attrString;
```

instead of

```
[[self.explainationTV textStorage] setAttributedString:attrString];
```

BTW it's *explanation*.